# Does having Azurite config in appsettings.json have any impact when deployed on Azure?

Tags: azure, .net-core, configuration, azure-webjobs

In my appsettings.json I have Azurite development config:

```
{
  ...
  "Azurite": {
    "UseDevelopmentStorage": true
  },
  ...
}
```

I'm using just one appsettings.json file in my Azure Web Jobs project since settings are overridden by Azure Web App → Configuration → Application Settings.

I'm not sure if having Azurite dev config in the settings file won't have any impact when deployed.

Can I ignore and leave it as it is or should I add another settings file, like local.settings.json?

Answer (score 1):

- Generally, the configurations set in the `appsettings.json` will be deployed to the `App service` => `Configuration` => `Application Settings` section.

I have taken references from the [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started#configure-storage-to-run-locally)

***Azurite with `appsettings.json` :***

- You can see I have tried with different options.

```cs
{
  "Azurite": {
    "UseDevelopmentStorage": true,
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
  },
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "UseDevelopmentStorage": true
  }
}
```

- As `Azurite` is only for the local development, you can see the values are not configured in `Application Settings`.
- As per the referred MS Doc, we need to set the same key with the Azure Storage Connection String in Azure App Settings.

[image]

> Can I ignore and leave it as it is or should I add another settings file, like local.settings.json?

- `local.settings.json` is only for working in the local environment.
- Even if you deploy the application with that file, you can see the `local.settings.json` file is not deployed to `Azure`.

[image]

In Production, Web Job uses `Azure Storage Accounts`.

- We need to set the `Azure Storage Account` connection string in the `Application Settings` of Azure App Service to work in Production environment.

> since settings are overridden by Azure Web App → Configuration → Application Settings.

We can either use `appsettings.json` or `app.config` file to configure App Settings in a Web Job.

If you want to configure any App settings for Azure Web Job using `app.config`, then Refer the [SOThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75996338/is-there-a-way-for-a-webjob-to-read-in-a-custom-configuration-section-like-apps) for setting the configurations.